# What is the use of second limit in the quantifier {m,n} in the regular expression in python if it used in a non-greedy way?

Tags: python, regex

The regular expression in Python `re.compile(r'\w{3,5}?')` will match with any pattern that have at least three non-overlapping alpha-numeric and underscore characters. My question here 'is the second limit has any use in this non greedy use of quantifier {3,5}, i.e. even if the five is replaced by any other number the result would be same. i.e. `re.compile(r'\w{3,5}?')=re.compile(r'\w{3,6}?')=re.compile(r'\w{3,7}?')=re.compile(r'\w{3,}?')`
Can some one give me an example where the second limit find any use?

Comment: Suppose a{3,5} will match from 3 to 5 'a' characters. For further clarification on re refer this link (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a lazily quantified pattern appears at the end of the pattern, it matches the *minimum*  amount of chars it needs to match to return a value. A `123(\w*?)` will always yield no value inside Group 1 as `*?` matches *zero* or more chars, but *as few as possible*.

It means that `\w{3,5}?` regex will always match 3 word chars, and the second argument will be "ignored" as it is enough to match 3 occurrences of the word char.

If the lazy pattern is not at the end, the second argument is important.

See an example: [`Test: (\w{3,5}?)-(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/1zV8jy/1) captures different amount of chars in Group 1 depending on how match word chars there are in the strings.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this example is what I have been looking for.